# How do I loop through a directory of PDF files and write the information to a Pandas Dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I am very new to Python, Pandas, and NLP but have taken a few intro courses. I have a directory of 3 PDF files (will be over a hundred once I get the full data set). I want to open each file and make two columns in a Pandas dataframe that I can eventually use for some NLP work. The two columns needed are an ID column with the name of the PDF and the second column is just all of the text/information located within that PDF

This is the code I used to go through one file at a time:

```
import PyPDF2 as pdf
i = 0
    while i < pdf_reader.getNumPages():
        pageinfo = pdf_reader.getPage(i)
        print(pageinfo.extractText())
        i = i + 1
```

This is the code that I used to name my directory and print out the file names:

```
import os
directory = os.listdir('test_files/')
directory = os.listdir('test_files/')
for entry in directory:
    print(entry)
```

**Update, this is what I have so far. Does it seem close?

```
directory = os.listdir('test_files/')
for entry in directory:
    file = open(entry,'rb')
    pdf_reader = pdf.PdfFileReader(file)
    i = 0
    while i < pdf_reader.getNumPages():
        pageinfo = pdf_reader.getPage(i)
        i = i + 1
    data = {'PDF_ID':[entry],
       'Text_Data': [pageinfo.extractText()]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['PDF_ID','Text_Data'])
```

would be ideal, but I haven't found the best way combine them and create a dataframe at the same time. I already have a function created that will clean and tokenize the text, but one file at a time is not ideal. Thanks!

Comment: Which library are you using for reading PDFs?

Comment: Apologies, meant to put that in there. I am using PyPDF2

Comment: sorry, but the question isn't very clear. what would the columns in the dataframe look like?

Comment: I want it to have two columns, one column with the name of the file or an ID field then the second column to just have all of the text from the PDF. After I have a a dataframe with those two I will be able to tokenized and clean the data